Go HTTP library is randomizing headers order
I've made Go code which sends http2 proxied request.
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
    MaxVersion:         tls.VersionTLS13,
    NextProtos:         []string{"h2", "http/1.1"},
    ServerName:         u.Hostname(),
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    CipherSuites:       selectedCipherSuites,
}
proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://" + proxy)
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
        TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
        ForceAttemptHTTP2: true,
    },
}

There is tls + ForceAttemptHTTP2, it sends http2 request to server. And in code it looks like this:
headers := req.Header
    headers.Set("Accept",  acceptHeader)
    headers.Set("Accept-Encoding", acceptEncoding)
    headers.Set("X-Forwarded-For", ip)
    headers.Set("Accept-Language", acceptLanguage)

    headers.Set("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile",  "?0")
    headers.Set("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform",  "\"Windows\"")

    headers.Set("Sec-Fetch-Dest",  "document")
    headers.Set("Sec-Fetch-Mode",  "navigate")
    headers.Set("Sec-Fetch-Site",  "none")
    headers.Set("Sec-Fetch-User",  "?1")

    headers.Set("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    headers.Set("User-Agent",  userAgent)

So I want order of headers to be like this cause of bot detections that cdn's have, so they dont block me. But when I tested, I have received headers this way:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, br
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Language: bn-BD,bn;q=0.8
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

So, it gets randomied, it's just one example, I recognized that every request it's different.
And here is what exactly sends request.
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, target, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating request:", err)
    }

+
        response, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer response.Body.Close()

I've tried everything that I could. Asked open ai to help but without any results.
Also I've tried this https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/105755 but maybe it doesnt work for http2.
So, how to make order of headers to be in order which I wanted to be exactly while sending HTTP2 request with http/net library in Go, with TLS?

Headers are stored in a map, you cannot set the order. Maybe try an alternative implementation, like fasthttp?

@JimB To my knowledge, the order of headers within one http request  MUST not have any semantic value. That was explicitly stated in the (outdated) RFC2616 (#4.2), and was not changed in any RFC that obsoleted it.

@MarkusWMahlberg: While this is true, common user agents use each their own specific order which then gets used for fingerprinting clients in  the context of bot detection. Looks like the client from the OP got blocked and they try to pass through this block by enforcing the same header order as common (i.e. allowed) user agents show. So it does not matter here what the RFC says, it matters what the server side bot detection expects.

@SteffenUllrich Thank you for pointing this out, but I was aware of this. I was trying to subtly point out that different means should be used. Cloudflare for example has the Cloudflare Bot Verification Process.

"req" seems to support setting a specific header order: https://req.cool/docs/tutorial/set-header/ . I know nothing about it though, so I only note it's existence. I don't consider it an answer.

https://req.cool/docs/tutorial/set-header/ is for http1, it doesn't do anything for me because I'm using http2 with proxy.
